# Capturing a line from multiline text based on search string

Tags: python, regex, full-text-search, substring, restructuredtext

I have a piece of reStructuredText, similar to this:

```
.. |icon_plain| raw:: html

   <span class="icon-dbs dark-green"></span>
```

Given that I know where to start search (I have a string `icon_plain`), what would be the best way to capture line 3 and return it?

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean "the best possible ever" way :) What I meant is, it is possible to do it in few ways - regex, python built in functions, maybe with a help of docstring... I'm not sure which one is the "the easiest" and "the most elegant" way given tools available around. I tried a bit with regex, but my knowledge of it made me stuck at some point... I can do it with Python, but instead of reinventing the wheel, I decided to come here and ask for an advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a string: icon_plain;you know target text in third line

```
target = reStructuredText.split('icon_plain')[1].split('\n')[2].strip()
```